# Naming Jews after both father and mother

Tags: names

A Jew is traditionally named after his father -- for example, Yonah ben Yonatan, except for a mishebberach when he is sick, when he is named after his mother -- for example, Yonah ben Sarah.

But some non-traditional Jews want to always be named after both parents -- for example, Yonah Ben Yonatan v'Sarah.

Is there anything in Jewish law against that?

Comment: It's common amongst even very traditional Sephardic Jews in Israel. Precident: Yoav Ben Tzeruya

Comment: @Mordechai Earlier Precident: Shaul ben Hacknanit.